# Datastax DSE Cassandra, Spark, Shark, Standalone Programm

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, apache-spark, shark-sql

I use Datastax Enterprise 4.5. I hope I did the config right, I did it like on datastax website explained. I can write into the Cassandra DB with an Windowsservice, this works but i can't query with Spark using the where function.

I start the Cassandra node (there is only one for test purpose) with "./dse cassandra -k -t" (in the /bin folder) so hadoop and spark are running both. I can write into Cassandra without a problem.

So you cannot use a 'where' clause in a Cassandra query when the 'where' isn't the RowKey. So I need to use Spark/Shark. I can start and use all queries I need with shark (./dse shark) but I need to write a Standalone program in Scala or Java.

So I tried this link: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

And I can query a simple statement like:

```
val conf = new SparkConf(true)
  .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "MY_IP")
  .setMaster("spark://MY_IP:7077")
  .setAppName("SparkTest")

// Connect to the Spark cluster:
lazy val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("keyspace", "tablename")
println(rdd.first)
```

and this works well but if I ask for more line or count:

```
println(rdd.count)
rdd.toArray.foreach(println)
```

then I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: All masters are unresponsive! Giving up.
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1049)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1033)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1031)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1031)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:635)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:635)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:635)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessActor$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:1234)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

When I try this in Java I have the same problem. Does anyone know this problem? I dont know if the DB config is correct or if the scala/Javaprogram works correct. Maybe some Ports a blocked but 7077 and 4040 are open.

Sidenote: If I start spark on the Cassandra DB, I can do queries like:

```
sc.cassandraTable("test","words").select("word").toArray.foreach(println)
```

But if I use a "where" clause like:

```
sc.cassandraTable("test","words").select("word").where("word = ?","foo").toArray.foreach(println)
```

I get this exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Exception during query execution: SELECT "word" FROM "test"."words" WHERE token("word") > 0 AND word = ? ALLOW FILTERING
```

Do you have an Idea why? I thought I can use where clauses in spark?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this is my solution. It is not the answer to all of my questions but it works for me and I wanna share it to you.

I use the hive jdbc driver to access a SharkServer with Java. How It works:

Start sharkserver: `bin/dse shark --service sharkserver -p <port>`

Dependencies for Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
    <version>0.20.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Java Code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://YOUR_IP:YOUR_PORT/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String sql;
    ResultSet res;



    sql = "SELECT * FROM keyspace.colFam WHERE name = 'John'";
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
        System.out.println(res.getString("name"));
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
All masters are unresponsive!
```

Implies that the IP you are attempting to connect to is not actually bound by spark. So this is basically a networking configuration error. Scan to see which interfaces are listening on 7077 and make sure you are connecting to the correct interface.

As for the second question, the `where` operator implies you are going to do a predicate pushdown on that clause. Currently you cannot do this with primary keys. If you want to `where` on a single primary key you can do a `filter` to accomplish that but you will not see great performance as this will do a whole table scan.

Comment: Version 1.1 of the connector will have support for primary keys in `where`. The patch for this has been already committed to the master branch.

Comment: But when `All masters are unresponsive!` why does it work on a single query like `.first`. That implies to me that the connection and die port work fine, right? Or is there a fallacy? Does it work in a differed way (use other ports etc.) if use `.first`?

Comment: That implies to me that the connection and die port work fine, right? Or is there a fallacy? Does it work in a differed way (use other ports etc.) if use `.first`?

I have seen the `.filter` function but this loads all data into the program and does the filtering there, but that's definitely to slow. 

I just want to have the functionality, same as shark, in my standalone program, I thought spark will do that. If not please tell  me what to use instead.

Comment: Adding the where clause in Shark will have the same effect.